# Jupyter : running a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, model, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook in Windows 10 PC.
I am trying to run 3 models in a dictionary (Logistic, KNeighbors, and RandomForestClassifier)
I went into the miniconda environment and started jupyter notebook.

The dataset is properly loaded, split to 'X' and 'y' and fitted properly.

I am trying to predict target values from a dataset by using 3 types of models which are packed in a dictionary.

I then created a function which has a loop which cycles through the dictionary and provides answers for each model, that will be fed to the empty dictionary **model_scores{}*

When I try to run the function I get an error which is provided below.

ny code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

# models from scikit-learn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# model evaluations
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score


models = {"Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
         "KNN": KNeighborsClassifier(),
         "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier()}

def fit_and_score(models, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    np.random.seed(42)
    model_scores = {}
    for name, model in models.items():
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        model_scores[name] = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    return model_scores

model_scores = fit_and_score(models=models,
                            X_train=X_train,
                            X_test=X_test,
                            y_train=y_train,
                            y_test=y_test)
```

the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-45006ce4a749> in <module>
      1 # run the function
      2 
----> 3 model_scores = fit_and_score(models=models,
      4                             X_train=X_train,
      5                             X_test=X_test,

<ipython-input-67-005647140cd3> in fit_and_score(models, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
     22     for name, model in models.items():
     23         # fit the model to the data
---> 24         model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     25         # evaluate the model and append its score to model_scores
     26         model_scores[name] = model.score(X_test, y_test)

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1405         else:
   1406             prefer = 'processes'
-> 1407         fold_coefs_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
   1408                                **_joblib_parallel_args(prefer=prefer))(
   1409             path_func(X, y, pos_class=class_, Cs=[C_],

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1039             # remaining jobs.
   1040             self._iterating = False
-> 1041             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1042                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1043 

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    857                 return False
    858             else:
--> 859                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    860                 return True
    861 

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    775         with self._lock:
    776             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 777             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    778             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    779             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in _logistic_regression_path(X, y, pos_class, Cs, fit_intercept, max_iter, tol, verbose, solver, coef, class_weight, dual, penalty, intercept_scaling, multi_class, random_state, check_input, max_squared_sum, sample_weight, l1_ratio)
    760                 options={"iprint": iprint, "gtol": tol, "maxiter": max_iter}
    761             )
--> 762             n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
    763                 solver, opt_res, max_iter,
    764                 extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)

F:\UdemyProjects\DataScienceZTM\heart-disease-project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py in _check_optimize_result(solver, result, max_iter, extra_warning_msg)
    241                 "    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/"
    242                 "preprocessing.html"
--> 243             ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
    244             if extra_warning_msg is not None:
    245                 warning_msg += "\n" + extra_warning_msg

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 0):

After importing the `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`, you are using `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` without defining them.

here i used a `Social_Network_Ads.csv` random dataset found on internet and it works without showing any error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,cross_val_score
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)


def fit_and_score(models, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    np.random.seed(42)
    model_scores = {}
    for name, model in models.items():
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        model_scores[name] = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    return model_scores

model_scores = fit_and_score(models=models,
                            X_train=X_train,
                            X_test=X_test,
                            y_train=y_train,
                            y_test=y_test)
```

Comment: Although you are technically right, the error message does not imply this (it would be different in case a variable was not defined); OP may have already defined these variables without showing it here.